# How to pass a value to a jsp variable from a Java Controller

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have following code within my .jsp:

```
    <% for(int i=0; i <= 10; i++) 
{ %>
    <TR>
        <td>${values[i][0]}</td>
        <td>${values[i][1]}<input type="button" width="60" value="EDIT"></td>
        <td>${values[i][2]}<input type="button" width="60" value="RESET"></td>
    </TR>
<% } %>
```

My Controller Class in Java returns an Array, which I want to be assigned to the jsp's variable:

```
    model.addAttribute("values", results);
```

How do I do this?

Comment: It should work, What is the issue you are facing? I hope you have necessary name space settings in web.xml

Comment: the entries stay empty, but the Controler's object is not empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your EL expression, `${values[i][0]}` this is not proper.

try this code:

```
<c:forEach var="value" items="${values}">
    <td>${value.name}</td> <!-- will be attributes of the object stored in controller -->
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: What do you mean not proper? It is proper EL expression